# difference between Too Many Requests and Too many attempts in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

im familiar with the idea of rate limiting , but sometimes i get Too many attempts error , sometimes i get Too Many Requests error (i got that recently sending request via Http from one server to another both running laravel )

in the laravel document i've seen a reference to `Too many attempts` but nothing about `Too Many Requests`   ... so what is the difference ?

Comment: Sounds like _probably_ two different phrases for the same thing. But we have no context for when you're getting these errors, or what documentation you're talking about.

Comment: As you haven't shared any code of your application, it's impossible to tell you why it returns that one response sometimes, and the other at other times

Comment: @NicoHaase im asking about the difference between these two errors as the both seem to be talking about the same thing ... so what's the difference  ? im not asking about my code so my code is irrelevant

Comment: @ADyson yes `two different phrases for the same thing` , but since they are produced by laravel there must be a difference in what is triggering them

Comment: Under some conditions, your application throws the first error; under other conditions, it throws the second one. How should we know why your application uses one or the other? This is not some kind of standard thing, your application could even throw one of these errors when something completely different happens, even if there is no error at all

Comment: @NicoHaase yes but there must be a fundamental difference between these two groups of conditions since they produce different error message ... im asking about laravel logic , not why im getting this error or whats wrong my code  look at MorganFreeFarm answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Too Many Requests:** This error is typically related to HTTP rate limiting. Laravel provides a way to throttle requests using its middleware.

**Too many attempts:** This is commonly seen in contexts like login attempts. Laravel provides features to limit the number of times a user can attempt certain actions to protect against things like brute force attacks. If a user tries to log in too many times with incorrect credentials, Laravel might lock out the user for a certain period and show a "Too many attempts" error.

This isn't an HTTP standard message like "Too Many Requests"

Comment: thanx it's rare to get a helpful answer/comment for these types of questions